# Problem with installing MSSQL driver on sail

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I want to install SQL server driver for php on laravel sail, after building containers Docker cannot install sql server driver. I'm getting trying to access array offset error ..

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-7.4/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    memcached:
        image: 'memcached:alpine'
        ports:
            - '11211:11211'
        networks:
            - sail
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
    rabbitmq:
        build: ./rabbitmq
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_RABBITMQ_NODE_HOST_PORT:-5672}:5672"
            - "${FORWARD_RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_HOST_PORT:-15672}:15672"
            - "${FORWARD_RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_HTTPS_HOST_PORT:-15671}:15671"
            - "${FORWARD_RABBITMQ_WEB_STOMP_HOST_PORT:-15674}:15674"
        privileged: true
        hostname: laradock-rabbitmq
        volumes:
            - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
            - ./rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
            - ./rabbitmq/management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmariadb:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

7.4/Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-dev \
       php7.4-pgsql php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-gd \
       php7.4-curl php7.4-memcached \
       php7.4-imap php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring \
       php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap \
       php7.4-intl php7.4-readline php7.4-pcov \
       php7.4-msgpack php7.4-igbinary php7.4-ldap \
       php7.4-redis php7.4-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN apt-get update \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php7.4
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

but I'm getting this error while installing sqlsrv extension
[image]

I don't know what to do. any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Well `FROM ubuntu:21.04` doesn't seem to agree with `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`. You should have seen error output from the docker-compose build process similar to `Some packages could not be installed` and `The following packages have unmet dependencies` and `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Refer to [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#ubuntu17) and choose the correct package URLs for your specific distro and release. If you don't know which distro and release an image is using you can always `docker run -it --rm YourImageNameHere cat /etc/os-release` to figure it out. But you already know that information here because `FROM ubuntu:21.04`